# How to slide content over with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, swift

I have a messaging view where the user can select emoticons to add to the message. I have a bar above the keyboard where the user can enter their message. It looks something like this: `H:|-[UIButton: emoticon]-[UITextField]-[UIButton: send]|`

Now I've tried to slide all these over by setting their left constraint to `constraint.constant -= screenWidth`, but this didn't seem to work, as I got loads of "Could not satisfy constraints" messages in the log and none of them moved. I also had the problem of not knowing where to put the emoticons (it's a bar of `UIButton` with one emoji each).

Is there a way to do this in a simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're doing right (you're sparse on the details), your problem is that your constraints are still pinned to the start and end.

You will probably need to remove the last item's right constraint before you can scroll anything.

That said, what I usually do in cases like this is wrap everything that's supposed to scroll in a plain UIView. Then I can keep their internal constraints the same, and only the UIView is pinned to the left and right of its superview. To scroll, I simply add a width constraint with the current width, remove the right constraint, and then subtract from the left constraint's constant to scroll it off screen.

That extra view gives me a guarantee that everything stays the size and location it had at the beginning of the animation, and might even allow me to optimize the animation (e.g. I can rasterize the view before I scroll it out, and UIKit then only has to move one layer).